# Failure rule for cucumber-jvm

Tags: java, rest, cucumber-jvm, rule

I am writing test suite for Rest APIs using cucumber-java. I was trying to use @Rule, however I found it was not supported by cucumber-jvm. Is there any option to write a rule on step failure ?

I am need to print the request-response on assertion failure (I'm asserting on the http response status), so that I can get an understanding on what went wrong?

Any help on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber-jvm has the [@After](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cucumber/cucumber_hooks.htm)  annotation and you could put something in there but why not simply include the response in the assertion statement failure text?

I use [rest-assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) to manage my HTTP request-responses.  My responses end up in objects of class Response.  To get the entire response, I might code this:

```
response.getBody().prettyPrint()
```

**EDIT**

You specified request as well.  Given requestSpec is the instance of class RequestSpecification that we initialized with the request values, I use

```
requestSpec.given().log().all()
```

to get the request into string form.

So using JUnit [assertTrue](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue(boolean))

```
assertTrue("REST service x Status Code =" + response.getStatusCode() + 
  ", for request = " + requestSpec.given().log().all() + ",\n response = " +
  response.getBody().prettyPrint(), response.getStatusCode() == 200);
```